# How to append value based on <th> tag in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

[image]

friends the A and B is group name and i listed clubs in left side table when user can double click the clubs then remove club from left table and i add the club in right side table based on radio button clicked please help me friends i no need to append black space in the right side table

My Html Code :

```
   <table class="tabledesign" id="Table1" border="1px"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="650px">
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Groups)
           { %>
        <td class="Group">
            <input id="Recipt" type="radio" class="GroupName" name="GroupName" value="<%: item.GroupName %>" /> <%: item.GroupName %>                
        </td>
        <%} %>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <div style="width: 240px;height: 300px; over-flow: auto;"  class="loginField">
     <table id="table" class="tbldesign" style="table-layout:fixed; margin-top : 0px;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
            <a href="" title="Click Header to Sort">CLUBS FOR THIS TOURNAMNET</a>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% foreach(var item in Model.ClubTour) {%>
        <tr>
        <td class="TdClick">
            <%: item.ClubId %> <input type="hidden" class="ClubId" name="ClubId" value="<%: item.ClubId %>" />                
        </td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 460px;height: 300px; over-flow-x: auto; over-flow-y: auto; float:right;"  class="loginField">
     <table id="table2" class="tbldesign" style="table-layout:fixed; margin-top : 0px;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Groups)
           {%>
        <th style="width:100px;" id="<%: item.GroupName %>">
            <a href="" title="Click Header to Sort"> <%: item.GroupName %> </a>
        </th>
        <%} %>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>    
        <tr>            
        </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
```

My Code jquery:

```
     $('.TdClick').dblclick(function () {
                var radio = $('.GroupName').length;
                var data = $(this).find('[name = "ClubId"]').val();
                if ($('input[name=GroupName]:checked').length <= 0) {
                    alert("Select Group Name");
                }
                else {
                    var valu = $('input[name=GroupName]:checked').val();
                    $('#table2 tbody').find('[id="'+ valu +'"]').append(data + "<input type='hidden' name='"+ valu +"' value='"+ data +"' />");
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }
            });
```

Tdclick is table right side table td class name (club names) 
name=GroupName is hidden value input

Comment: your markup to take a look at.

Comment: i cannot understand are talking about check list but my requirement is drag and drop or like this only

Comment: Friend another thing is <tr> appending is not a problem but it need to avoid parallel td Empty

Comment: i meant if you could show us your html too.

Comment: Yes i Update my Question Friend